# Imaginary numbers calculation for DFT

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, euler-mascheroni-constant

I am trying to understand the Fourier transformation and the math behind it, so I was trying to use this formula:

$$ x_k = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_n e^{-\frac{j2{\pi}kn}{N}} $$

to calculate all $ x_{0\ldots3} $ for $N = 4$ and

$$
x = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_0 \\
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\
2 - {j} \\
-{j} \\
-1 + 2{j}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If I want to calculate $ x_1 $:

\begin{align}
x_1 & = x_0\cdot e^{-\frac{{j}2{\pi}1 \cdot 0}{4}} + x_1\cdot e^{-\frac{{j}2{\pi}1{\cdot}1}{4}} + x_2\cdot e^{-\frac{j2\pi1\cdot2}{4}} + x_3\cdot e^{-\frac{j2\pi1\cdot 3}{4}} \\[8pt]
x_1 & = x_0\cdot e^0 + 
x_1\cdot e^{-\frac{j\pi}{2}} + x_2\cdot e^{-j\pi} + x_3\cdot e^{-\frac{3j\pi}{2}} \\[8pt]
x_1 & = 1 + (2-j)\cdot e^{-\frac{j\pi}{2}} - j\cdot e^{-j\pi} + (-1 + 2j)\cdot e^{-\frac{3j\pi}{2}}
\end{align}

so according to Wikipedia's articles for [DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) this should be equal to $ x_1 = -2 - 2j $ but I am missing the last step.

I got a hint that I should use the [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) that $ e^{j\pi} + 1 = 0 $ but I am still unable to simplify it to $ x_1 = -2 - 2j $

[EDIT] I wanted to share my solution here, which might help some people in the future: 
According to Euler's formula: 
$ e^{jx} = \cos(x) + j\sin(x) $, $ j^2 + 1 = 0 $.
We can then simplify the following expressions to:
\begin{align}
e^{-\frac{j\pi}{2}} & = \cos\Big(-\frac{\pi}{2}\Big) + j\sin\Big(-\frac{\pi}{2}\Big) = 0 - j = -j \\[6pt]
e^{-j\pi} & = \cos(-\pi) + j\sin(-\pi) = -1 + j\cdot0 = -1 \\[6pt]
e^{-\frac{3j\pi}{2}} & = \cos\Big(-\frac{3\pi}{2}\Big) + j\sin\Big(-\frac{3\pi}{2} \Big) = 0 + j\cdot1 = j \\[6pt]
e^{-2j\pi} & = \cos(-2\pi) + j\sin(-2\pi) = 1 
\end{align}
Knowing that the cosinusoidal and sinusoidal functions have the same value every $ 2\pi $ and opposite sign every $ \pi $ intervals we can easily calculate the other functions if needed.

$$
x_1 = 1 + (-j)(2 - j) - j(-1) + j(-1 + 2j) = 1 + j(-2 + j + 1 - 1 + 2j)
$$
$$
x_1 = 1 + j(-2 + 3j)  = 1 - 2j + 3j^2 = 1 - 2j - 3(-1) = -2 - 2j
$$

Comment: Your way of writing MathJax code is weird. You use "align" when you have only one line, but then you use it three times, one for each line, when you wan the three lines aligned with each other. That makes no sense. Enclosing \cdot in {curly braces} causes a lack of proper spacing. And you wrote a lot of things like {2}{j}{\pi} where 2j\pi would suffice.

Comment: yes, that's true, I am a bit new to Latex style formatting that is why I have used more curly braces than needed. Any idea how I can align to the left more than one line? This was also the case why I have used so much `align` statements.

Comment: Use a backslash in \cos and \sin. This does not only prevent italicization, but it also results in context-dependent spacing. For example in $\sin x$ you see more space to the right of $\sin$ than you see in $\sin(x).$ At one point in your posting I saw $j{\sin}$ and changed it to $j\sin,$ where you see more space between $j$ and $\sin.$ That is not manually added spacing; rather I simply changed j{\sin} to j\sin. The space to the left of $\sin$ was not applied because nothing (within the braces) was to the left of $\sin.$ Also, see my edits to see how to align things.

Comment: I prefer to write $\displaystyle \frac 1 2 e^{-1/2}$ rather than $\displaystyle \frac 1 2 e^{-\frac 1 2}.$ It seems easier on the eyes that way. $\qquad$

Comment: agree with you, thanks for the corrections and the hints, Michael, I am still new to Latex formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Using Euler's formula tells you that 
$$
e^{-j\pi/2} = -j, \quad e^{-j \pi} = -1, \quad e^{-3j\pi/2} = j.
$$

Comment: thanks, I have solved it.